# Mass Update MySQL DB from CSV

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-workbench

I just added a new field to my Rails app which uses a MySQL DB.  I have a CSV which contains values for the new field (name) for records already in the table.

```
Article (table)
_______________
id | name
```

In the first field of the CSV is the id field and in the second is the name.  I want to update the Article table by updating the name field based on the id field in the CSV.  Can someone please help me write a MySQL query for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CSV.open('file_path.csv', 'r').each do |row|
  article = Article.find_by_id(row[0])

  article.update_attribute(:name, row[1]) if article
end
```

I used `find_by_id` because it returns `nil` if nothing is found, whereas `find` returns an exception ActiveRecord::recordNotFound.